# Neural network output exactly correlated with output layer bias weights (Keras)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I'm implementing a neural network in Keras and after several rounds of training, the network output becomes completely correlated with the bias weights in the output layer. Because of this, the network output is the same regardless of the input. This data has previously produced good results but I've done something to cause this problem. One of the changes I made was to make the network easier to adjust and I instantiate it like:

```
layers = [40, 8, 4]    
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(layers[0], input_dim=np.shape(train_x_scaled)[1], activation='relu'))
for layer_size in layers[1:]:
    model.add(Dense(layer_size, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(np.shape(train_y_scaled)[1], activation='sigmoid'))
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse']) 
history = model.fit(train_x_scaled, train_y_scaled, epochs=iters)
```

The training input is of shape (1513, 3048) and the target is of shape (1513, 254).

Comment: Hello, I think the problem comes from the fact that you have more features than datas. As a result, the model is not able to create a proper mapping and tend to output the average of your datas. Did you try some dimensions reductions (PCA or TF-IDF if you are working on BoW) ?

Comment: I've thought about that but haven't yet addressed that issue. I've had a successful run with similar dimensions so I don't think that's the issue but I'll pursue that path as I'm continuing my troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my problem. My network shape was 3048, 40, 8, 4, 254. By necking down so small just prior to the output, it limited the decisions that could be described and the network just learned to ignore the input. I did have one successful training run with this shape so I suspect I was just lucky with the weight initialization in that instance. I changed the network to 3048, 40, 8, 40, 254 I was able to get useful training done again.